# " ' " is converting into " â€™ " while copying contents of one file to another

Tags: java, file, file-handling

Here, I'm trying to copy the contents of one file to another. The contents must be exactly the same but I'm getting some anomalies.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw =null;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the input file name");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the output file name");
        String output = scan.nextLine();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(input), "UTF-8"));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(output)));
            int ch = 0;
            while((ch = br.read()) != -1){
                bw.write((char)ch);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if(br != null && bw != null){
                br.close();
                bw.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

User must enter input file name and the contents of input file will be copied into the entered output file name.

**testInput.txt**

> **I’d** given myself a year to start a new magazine in Berlin to capture
>   the zeitgeist, enjoying the **city’s** cultural foment while facing the
>   expected challenges raising the necessary cash.

**testOutput.txt**

> **Iâ€™d** given myself a year to start a new magazine in Berlin to capture
>   the zeitgeist, enjoying the **cityâ€™s** cultural foment while facing the
>   expected challenges raising the necessary cash.

Comment: If you don't specify a charset for writing, the default one of the platform will be used.

Comment: @Arnaud I have tried "UTF-8" as an argument to OutputStreamWriter. It's not working.

Comment: If you're only copying the file (not doing anything with the contents) then you don't need a Reader and Writer -- just use InputStream and OutputStream to copy the raw bytes regardless of character encoding. Better yet, use a library like Guava or Apache commons-io to handle the copying for you.

Comment: At least specify why I'm getting down-votes.

Comment: What do you use to view the input, what to view the output? What are the actual binary values in the file?

Comment: @dnault tried InputStream, getting same anomaly.

Comment: @AbhinavKushagra Still seeing the character encoding issues without a Reader / Writer? That doesn't make sense. You might want to double-check that you're actually running the code you think you're running.

Comment: @dnault Here's the code https://writexo.com/mh1pkmyg

Answer (score 1):

The comment "What do you use to view the input, what to view the output?" is what you should act upon.

What is it that made you arrive at the conclusion that the "contents" of the output include those euro and tm signs ?  Strings in text files have an encoding too, and the first thing you must think about is to be sure that the tool you use for viewing actually handles that encoding correctly.

Strange tokens preceded by an â often betray utf-8 encoded files viewed with a primitive tool like notepad that is assuming a one-byte-per-character enoding scheme, often iso-8859-1.  The error is not in the file, it's in the choice of viewing tool.

To put it otherwise : files contain only bytes.  Even if they are suffixed ".txt".  Even if those bytes represent "just strings" it is still the case that encoding/decodig has happened and that every single tool in the chain from creation/writing of the bytes to viewing/reading the bytes must be aware of which encoding was used.  Tools very often blindly assume the machine's default encoding, and in these days where utf-8 is definitely gaining traction, that assumption is often wrong.  (Especially on windows machines.)

Answer (score 0):

try 

`bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                    new FileOutputStream(output), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));`
becouse OutputStreamWriter  documentations says:

> If you do not specify one, it simply uses the default file encoding of
>   the default locale.

Comment: I appreciate you suggesting try-with-resources ;) but some explanation would be in order to make the answer more helpful.

Comment: giving me same output

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to character encoding.

You're using `UTF-8` but it appears it can't display the `’` character (which is ASCII character [8217](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/8217)).

So, you can either:

1. Use the encoding as `CP1252` (`br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       new FileInputStream(input), "CP1252"));`)
2. Or use ASCII character 39 - the [apostrophe](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/39).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the contents as it is you should use method without the charset parameter. In this case it will choose the default style.

```
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(input)));
   ...
}
```